# Span of Vectors equal

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$S= \{a,b,c\}$,
$T= \{a,b,a+b,b+c\}$
and $S,T$ both belong to vector space $V$ over $R$.

Can we compare $L(S)$ and $L(T)$? L represents the linear span of vector

How to show these two spans are equal?

Comment: What is $L(T)$? The linear span of the vectors in $T$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! What is $L(T)$,$L(S)$? is it $\text{span}(T)$ and $\text{span}(S)$?

Comment: We show two spans are equal in the same ways as showing two sets are equal. i.e. a vector in one span is also in another.

Comment: Yes, it is span(T) and span(S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider s to be an element of S. So it can be written as s = k1 a + k2 b + k3 c, where k1 ,k2, k3 Є R.Observe that      s =  k3(b+c) + (k2-k3)b +k1a +0.(a+b) i.e S ⊆ T. Again u can (similar type as before) show that if t Є T then it can be written as the linear combination of a,b,c. So T ⊆ S . So the span of T and S are same.

I apologize for being unable to write properly in latex format.(I wrote in word)

Comment: Thankyou so much